# Wordpress Gutenberg: custom block for nested containers layout

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to create a custom block that saves/generates a nested container structure:

```
[container]
   [nested container]
       [content blocks like headline, paragraph, image, buttons]
   [/nested container]

   [nested container]
       [content blocks like headline, paragraph, image, buttons]
   [/nested container]
   .
   .
   .
[/container]
```

So the ability to add a container, add nested containers and any contents inside thes nested containers.

I am able to do the css and enqueue part, but the neccessary javascript to achieve such a nested structure is beyond me.

Thanks, Georg

Answer (score 0):

[Block Patterns](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-patterns/) may be an easier approach than creating a custom block for your scenario.

Using the Visual Editor, you can quickly create the desired nested layout, then switch to Code Editor (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + M) to get the markup for your Block Pattern, eg:

**PHP**

```php
// Register your own category
register_block_pattern_category('custom', array(
    'label' => __('Custom', 'my-plugin')
));

// Register block pattern
register_block_pattern('my-plugin/heading-para-img-buttons', array(
    'title' => __('Heading, Paragraph, Image with Buttons', 'my-plugin'),
    'categories' => array(
        'custom'
    ),
    'description' => _x('One heading, paragraph, image with buttons in a group', 'Block pattern description', 'my-plugin'),
    'content' => '<!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
                    <div class="wp-block-group"><!-- wp:heading {"level":3} -->
                    <h3 class="wp-block-heading">Heading</h3>
                    <!-- /wp:heading -->
                    
                    <!-- wp:paragraph -->
                    <p>Paragraph</p>
                    <!-- /wp:paragraph -->
                    
                    <!-- wp:image -->
                    <figure class="wp-block-image"><img alt=""/></figure>
                    <!-- /wp:image -->
                    
                    <!-- wp:buttons -->
                    <div class="wp-block-buttons"><!-- wp:button -->
                    <div class="wp-block-button"><a class="wp-block-button__link wp-element-button">Button A</a></div>
                    <!-- /wp:button -->
                    
                    <!-- wp:button -->
                    <div class="wp-block-button"><a class="wp-block-button__link wp-element-button">Button B</a></div>
                    <!-- /wp:button --></div>
                    <!-- /wp:buttons --></div>
                 <!-- /wp:group -->'
));
```

**Result**
[image: Custom Block Pattern]

The [Block Patterns directory](https://wordpress.org/patterns/) also has many great examples of what possible and freely available ones you can download and use inside WordPress.